# GET file://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I got this error message in my console :

> GET file://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I include my **Bootstrap** CDN like this in my head section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



<head>

    <title> Technical Requirements </title>


    <!-- CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Anybody have any idea why it produce this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're working in the file:// namespace, you can't use the // trick to get online resources. Change them to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's works. I'll make sure to accept this when I can. Thanks for your advice. :D